# Store uploads on an external server?

Tags: uploads, wp-config

I'm setting up an install of Wordpress on our server instances which are hosted with AWS. Of course, everything that's on our servers is in version control with git and there is no FTP so uploading anything like media or plugins directly to our servers is a no go.

What I'd like to do is host the core Wordpress files on our servers but save uploads on an external server. Ideally, this would be all of `wp_content/` but I'd settle for just `uploads/` if that's not possible. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Storing the entire `wp-content` folder means loading plugins and themes from a remote server which would have massive performance reductions as well as issues with URLs for assets. Restricting this question to uploads makes it much simpler, but you'd have to specify what it is that the other server is, e.g. is it a generic server? S3 bucket? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is with a plugin such as [WP Offload S3](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/).  It will take uploads to the media library and send them over to S3 and switch the URL to point to S3 for you.  I have used this with a group of autoscaling servers and it has been working well.